# Switch in Meteor template helper

Tags: javascript, meteor, helper

I have a template with a table created by iterating over an array of user selected companies, which are stored, by ticker symbol, in a document attribute called `selections`.  I show different values associated with each company, depending on a different user selection, called `metric`.

I am having trouble writing a helper with the if/else statement required to change the value depending on the user selection.  With the code below, `headingNum` and  `headingDen` are showing properly.  So is `companyName` which is associated with an individual selection.  If I replace `valuationNum` with `this.reported.capTable.enterpriseValue`, the correct value appears.  But I cannot get it to appear when using the helper.

```
<template name="Table">
    <div>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Company</th>
                    <th>{{headingNum}}</th>
                    <th>{{headingDen}}</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {{#each selections}}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{companyName}}</td>
                        <td>${{valuationNum}}</td>
                        <td>${{valuationDen}}</td>
                    </tr>
                {{/each}}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>
```

JS file

```
var metric = this.metric;
var period = this.period;
Template. Table.helpers({
    selections: function () {
        var selected = this.selections;
        return Companies.find({ticker: {$in: selected}})
    },
    headingNum: function () {
        switch (metric) {
            case "A":
                return "EV";
                break;
            case "B":
                return "Price";
                break;
            default:
                return "EV"
        }
    },
    valuationNum: function() {
        switch (metric) {
            case "A":
                return this.reported.capTable.enterpriseValue;
                break;
            case "B":
                return this.reported.capTable.lastClose;
                break;
            default:
                return ""
        }
    }
});
```

I tried breaking out the {{#each}}{{each}} block into a new template to see if it would help with the data context but no luck (and it messes up the table).

Am I writing these helpers correctly?
I also receive an error message in the JS file saying `reported` is an unresolved variable even though that is the correct path.

Thank you.

EDIT:

This helper works, not sure why the other doesn't:

```
headingNum: function () {
    var metric = this.metric;
    switch (metric) {
        case "EV/EBITDA":
            return "EV";
            break;
        case "Price/Earnings":
            return "Price";
            break;
        default:
            return ""
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Meteor's template is built on [blaze](http://meteor.github.io/blaze/), which is reactive by design. This means that the template will only re-render when the data dependency values change. In this example, only when you modify `Companies`. However, when you modify the value of `metric`, the template will not re-render, which is why you are not seeing the change you expect.

The reactive way of achieving your goal is actually putting in the metric switch logic right inside the template:

```
{{#each selections}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{companyName}}</td>
        {{#if metricA}}
        <td>${{reported.capTable.enterpriseValue}}</td>
        {{else}}
        <td>${{reported.capTable.lastClose}}</td>
        {{/if}}
        <td>${{valuationDen}}</td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Inside your JS:

```
Template. Table.helpers({
    metricA: function() {
        return this.metric == 'A';
    }
})
```

Comment: Not sure I follow.  Reactivity aside, I'm not sure why I can't get any initial value to appear.  I added additional code to my post showing a helper that I have that does work.  This one doesn't pull from any collection but the results all appear correctly without adding any code to the HTML file.  I would think the original switch helper would work here as well.

Comment: Also edited my post - I originally wrote that I couldn't get the value to "change". Should have said I couldn't get the value to "appear at all"

Answer (score 0):

Just having a quick browse over your code, just a few things.

You have set the metric and period variables at the window scope - not the template scope.  This is why your unable to access the metric variable within your helper.  To fix, just remove the var from where you initially create the metric variable.  This however, is not a good way to manage the scoping and variable management.

I would say to make this really effective, you want to have a helper and event handler to track the getting and setting of the metric reactively (reactive-var package helps for this)

Setup the metric reactive variable

```
Template.Table.created = function() {
  this.metric = new ReactiveVar();                                      
}
```

Get the Metric

```
Template.Table.helpers({
  getMetric: function() {
    return this.metric.get();
  }
})
```

Set the Metric

```
Template.Table.events({
  'click .setMetric': function(event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var metric = $(event.target).data('metric');
    if(metric) template.data.metric.set(metric);
  }
});
```

Then using these, as a strategy you could simply have a helper for your headings and values - determining the metric on demand and restricting it.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was doing something wrong with declaring those variables. As for everything else though, since the headingNum helper result changes correctly when I change the value of metric, I'm not sure why it would be necessary to write a reactive variable. It seems like the issue is that the data contexts for headingNum and for valuationNum different. But I don't know how to access each item in {{#each}}{{each}} through the helper (I can only access if I refer to one document path, like this.reported.capTable.enterpriseValue, directly in spacebars.

Comment: With your helper, pass it the parent data payload - {{headingNum ../}}

And 

headingNum: function (datapayload) {

}

Comment: Sorry have been away from this so just getting back to you comment - can you clarify what you mean by data payload?